# Подписать отправляемый XML с помощью ЭЦП

Tags: c#

Я нашел вот эту инструкцию, но не могу его реализовать на C#.

> Необходимо выполнить следующие действия:
>
> 1. Создать XML, используя XSD схему для подписываемых данных (Схему можно получить перейдя по ссылке
>    http://esf.gov.kz:8080/esf-web/ws/EsfXsdService?wsdl);
> 2. Убрать XML заголовок (строку вида `<?xml version="1.0"?>`)
> 3. Убрать все символы между XML тэгами (включая пробелы, табуляции и символы перевода строки);
> 4. Подписываемые данные должны начинаться с тега `<invoice>` и заканчиваться тегом `</invoice>`, исключая неймспейсы и префиксы.
>    Пример:
>
> ```xml
> <invoice>
>   <date>04.08.2016</date>
>   <invoiceType>ORDINARY_INVOICE</invoiceType>
>   <num>11111111111111121</num>
>   <operatorFullname>Идрисов Кайрат Ерикович</operatorFullname>
>   <signatureType>COMPANY</signatureType>
>   <customers>
>       <customer>
>           <address>г.Астана, ул. Мира д 24 кв 12</address>
>           <name>ТОО "АСЕМ-2"</name>
>           <statuses>
>               <status>NONRESIDENT</status>
>           </statuses>
>       </customer>
>   </customers>
>   <productSet>
>       <currencyCode>KZT</currencyCode>
>       <product>
>           <description>цемент</description>
>           <ndsAmount>0</ndsAmount>
>           <priceWithTax>2500</priceWithTax>
>           <priceWithoutTax>2500</priceWithoutTax>
>           <quantity>5</quantity>
>           <turnoverSize>2500</turnoverSize>
>           <unitNomenclature>тонна</unitNomenclature>
>           <unitPrice>500</unitPrice>
>       </product>
>       <product>
>           <description>доставка</description>
>           <ndsAmount>0</ndsAmount>
>           <priceWithTax>8000</priceWithTax>
>           <priceWithoutTax>8000</priceWithoutTax>
>           <quantity>1</quantity>
>           <turnoverSize>8000</turnoverSize>
>           <unitNomenclature>услуга</unitNomenclature>
>           <unitPrice>8000</unitPrice>
>       </product>
>       <totalExciseAmount>0</totalExciseAmount>
>       <totalNdsAmount>0</totalNdsAmount>
>       <totalPriceWithTax>10500</totalPriceWithTax>
>       <totalPriceWithoutTax>10500</totalPriceWithoutTax>
>       <totalTurnoverSize>10500</totalTurnoverSize>
>   </productSet>
>   <sellers>
>       <seller>
>           <bank>аТФ БАНК</bank>
>           <bik>KZKS456J</bik>
>           <iik>KZ012565854HG456253658FG</iik>
>           <kbe>19</kbe>
>           <name>ИП"Кайрат"</name>
>           <statuses>
>               <status>EXPORTER</status>
>           </statuses>
>           <tin>123456789011</tin>
>       </seller>
>   </sellers>
>   <turnoverDate>20.07.2016</turnoverDate>
> </invoice>
> ```
>
> Для формирования ЭЦП для ЭСФ, Вам необходимо скачать комплект
> разработчика SDK по адресу
> http://kgd.gov.kz/ru/content/api-interfeys-1
>
> 5. Используя локальный сервис(generateSignature в SDK) получить подпись для нужного ЭСФ.
> 6. Подписать ЭСФ полученной от локального сервиса подписью.
>
> Если Вы хотите реализовать генерацию подписи программным путем, просим
> выполнить следующие пункты:
>
> 7. Полученную в результате выполнения шагов 2-4 канонизированную строку необходимо подписать закрытым ключом:
>
> ```
> byte[] signature = sign(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), privateKey);
> ```
>
> 8. Полученный в результате подписания байтовый массив, т.е. подпись, необходимо преобразовать в base64-строку:
>
> ```
> String signatureBase64Type = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byte[] signature);
> ```
>
> 9. Вставить полученную подпись(signatureBase64Type) в теги  запроса веб-сервиса.
>
> ВАЖНО! Уважаемые разработчики, обратите внимание на реализацию шагов 7
> и 8 в вашей системе, так как в большинстве случаев причиной проблемы
> было именно отсутствие преобразования байтового массива в
> base64-строку.
>
> Верификацию полученной подписи можете осуществить следующим образом:
>
> ```
> X509Certificate cert = сертификат подписи пользователя;
> Signature s = Signature.getInstance(cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
> s.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
> s.update(invoiceXmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));                    
> boolean signatureVerificationResult = s.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature));
> ```

пока что нашел кода для получения certificate

```
// получение данные для certificate
try
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("key path.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
    byte[] signature = cert.GetRawCertData();
    
    String signatureBase64Type = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    Console.WriteLine(signatureBase64Type);
} 
catch (CryptographicException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

как я могу получить код для signature ?

Comment: Какой ответ вы ожидаете? Что кто то сделат вашу задачу за вас?

Comment: сорри, забыл, теперь дополнил )

Comment: Используя локальный сервис(generateSignature в SDK)

Answer (score 2):

1. Для начала пойми в каком виде / формате / контейнере у тебя хранится сертификат/открытый/закрытый ключи?
2. Есть весь сертификат или только открытая его часть? Обычно открытая часть передается вместе с подписью.
3. Тебе нужно только проверять подпись или подписывать тоже необходимо?
4. Какой используется крипто-провайдер. RSA или что-то другое?
   если нужна совместимость с Java ( а исходники в описании на ней приведены ) то смотри в сторону сборки Org.BouncyCastle для .NET, я с ее помощью пробовал реализовать RSA256 для авторизации JWT в Google FCM, более ничего в дотнете с PEM-форматом сертификата нормально не работало.